# Angular/4 - Route animation not working

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to implement route animations in an Angular CLI project using Angular/4. I have been trying to follow [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/04/19/angular-2-4-router-animation-tutorial-example) tutorial, but with limited success.

My code reads

/src/app/_animations/fadein.animation.ts

```
import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';

export const fadeInAnimation =
// trigger name for attaching this animation to an element using the 
[@triggerName] syntax
    trigger('fadeInAnimation', [

        // route 'enter' transition
        transition(':enter', [
         // css styles at start of transition
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
         // animation and styles at end of transition
        animate('3000ms', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ]),
]);
```

/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SlimLoadingBarService } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';

// import fade in animation
import { fadeInAnimation } from './../_animations/fadein.animation';

import { PickJob } from './../pick-jobs/pick-job';
import { PickJobService } from './../pick-jobs/pick-job.service';
import { FlashService } from './../flash/flash.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
    animations: [fadeInAnimation],
    host: { '[@fadeInAnimation]': '' }
})
export class DashboardComponent {}
```

/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="container_flex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn btn-block btn-primary block shadow">
                Print Next Pick Job
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-danger shadow" routerLink="/pick-jobs" routerLinkActive="menu-active">
                List Pick Jobs
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-warning shadow" routerLink="/cages/assign" routerLinkActive="menu-active">
                Print Pick Cage Labels
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

/src/app/app.module.ts

```
...
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [    
      ...
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ...
```

The animation never runs else, has completed prior to page load. Not sure which. Can anybody spot the error in my code? Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: Just a quick note that route animations are being changed (was suppose to be 4.1, will now be later) to solve problems like this, so you should be seeing more information about these things soon.

Comment: Have you gone through the docs? https://angular.io/guide/router#adding-animations-to-the-routed-component.  The tutorial you're using appears recent based on its date, but it is still out of date since he's using host metadata and not @HostBindings

Comment: Also, this is some Angular animation eye candy http://slides.yearofmoo.com/ng-japan-2017-demo/ and you can check out the associated slides http://slides.yearofmoo.com/ng-japan-2017-slides/#/0/0/, which contain route animation information

Comment: If you're using Angular Material check out or watch this issue, which appears to prevent route animations from occurring https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5107 in v4.2.2

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve a smooth fade out / in effect now using route animations.

Define your animation and route transitions it applies to:

```
const fadeIn = [
  query(':leave', style({ position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, opacity: 1 })),
  query(':enter', style({ position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, opacity: 0 })),
  query(':leave', animate('1s', style({ opacity: 0 }))),
  query(':enter', animate('1s', style({ opacity: 1 })))
]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  /* Allow CSS in this component to cascade down to child components */
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: [
    trigger('routerAnimations', [
      transition('* => *', fadeIn)
    ])
  ]
})
```

Annotate your router outlet in your template:

```
<div class="page" [@routerAnimations]="prepareRouteTransition(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Back in your *app.component.ts* implement the `prepareRouteTransition(outlet)` function:

```
prepareRouteTransition(outlet) {
    const animation = outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'] || {};
    return animation['value'] || null;
}
```

If you want custom animations depending on which route is coming/going, you need to add some metadata to your routes. Check out Matias Niemela's talk at ng-conf 2017 [here](https://youtu.be/Oh9wj-1p2BM?t=12m22s) for more info, but [his demo project](https://github.com/matsko/ng4-animations-preview) contains a working example.

Comment: the demo project is not working properly, will you provide the detailed code structure

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this one is easy and kinda subtle at first.

Don't use the `host` component property.  That's not doing anything for you.

Instead, what you want to do is add the synthetic property `@yourTrigger` to the "host" element of the component you want to animate.  If that component has a selector that is written in a template as `<app-dashboard>`, then what you're trying to do is add an "attribute": `<app-dashboard @yourTrigger>`

You can do this in the component itself with `@HostBinding`:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
    animations: [routeAnimation],
})
export class DashboardComponent {
    @HostBinding('@routeAnimation') routeAnimation = true;
}
```

`@HostBinding` sets a binding on the component's host element.  This is the same element you address with `:host` in your template's CSS.

Note that you need both the `animations` property on the component and the `@HostBinding` decorator.  The value of HostBinding should be the trigger you are using in the animation referenced in `fadeInAnimation`.  The tutorials always call this trigger `routeAnimation` and I'm not sure how special that is but it's probably a good practice.

Comment: I couldnot understand you. And I have tried what you said, same result Not Working

Comment: You also need to change the trigger in the animation to `routeAnimation`.